# Is it enough to install SP3 of SQL Server 2005 alone?

Tags: sql-server-2005, servicepacks

I installed SQL Server 2005, and I want to install service packs, I have service packs 1, 2, 3, but I want to know, Is it different to install just service pack 3? or I should install first SP1, the SP2 and finally SP3?

Comment: If you are a consultant and billing by the hour, then install all 3. :-)  But in truth, you don't need to, as Kyle pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service packs are cumulative, read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/bb895958.aspx). I think this belongs on SF though.

> Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Service Pack
>   3 (SP3) contains hotfixes that were
>   included in cumulative update packages
>   for SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 2
>   from cumulative update package 1 to
>   cumulative update package 9, and fixes
>   to issues that have been reported
>   through our customer feedback
>   platforms. It also includes
>   supportability enhancements and issues
>   that have been reported through
>   Windows Error Reporting.

Comment: It will more than likely be migrated, you can sit back. Stack is for development questions, SF for servers and administration, just to give you a guide for future.

Answer (score 0):

Install service pack 3.  If it wants you to install the rest, it will tell you.

I think the Sql Server team understands this situation may happen and have taken steps to account for it.

Or, better yet, go to Windows Update.  Hurr.